# In python 3 BeautifulSoup find command gives no result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I type the full name of the place I want, the result comes up, but when I leave it with *, it does not find any results and I think it gives an error. Do you have any solution suggestions? I would be glad if you explain with an example. thanks in advance for your time

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import wget
res = requests.post("https://store.rg-adguard.net/api/GetFiles", "type=CategoryId&url=7d949c6e-f0df-4325-b022-9e031ff18885&ring=WIS&lang=en-US", headers={
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
})
html = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")

a = html.find("a", string=re.compile(
    "54406Simizfo\.WSATools*\.msixbundle"))
    # 54406Simizfo.WSATools_0.1.56.0_neutral_~_f0x555vvp18ze.msixbundle
link = a["href"]
print(link)
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 12, in <module>
    link = a["href"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Usually, it is a good practice to use get() to avoid such errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using * in regex you have to encapsulate the expression.
Use:

```
"54406Simizfo\.WSATools(.)*\.msixbundle"
```

instead of just

```
"54406Simizfo\.WSATools*\.msixbundle"
```

(.) will match a single charachter. (.)* will match any number of charachters.